# the .set() method is not in the xml.etree library for Python?

Tags: python, xml, xml.etree

working on creating an XML file with some data using Python. I am trying to set values in dictionary to data in the list. I am going to be making multiple lines, so that is why I reference each value this way. Thanks guys. Here is my code:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element("painter")
root.set('version', '1.0')
linenum = 0
pointnum = 0

smpl_data = [[[20,40],(0,0,1,1)],[[10,50],(0,0,1,1)],[[78,89],(0,0,1,1)]]

while linenum <= len(smpl_data): #smpl_data change to self.lines
    elem_line = ET.SubElement(root,"line" + str(linenum), attrib={"r": "1", "g": "2", "b": "3", "a": "4"})
    print elem_line
    print elem_line.attrib.get("r")                       
    print elem_line.attrib.set("r", "smpl_data[linenum][2]")  
    # I get an attribute error: 'dict' object has no  attribute 'set'
```

It is clearly shown in the documentation though...

http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.set

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `get()` and `set()` on the `attrib` member of the `Element`.  `attrib` is a regular old Python dictionary that does not have a `set()` function.  The documentation you linked is for the `set()` function on the actual `Element` object itself.

To set a value in `attrib` member you would use:

```
elem_line.attrib['r'] = smpl_data[linenum][2]
```

If you want to use the `Element` instead:

```
elem_line.get('r')
elem_line.set('r', smpl_data[linenum][2])
```

Comment: Thanks this helped a ton! I realized I needed to do smpl_data[linenum][1][0] to access value "r", but elem_line.get("r"), and elem_line.set("r", smpl_data...) work great.